# Too many questions about US elections

Tags: discussion

Am I the only one who think there is way too many questions about US elections, and no questions about politics in general anywhere else?

I believe US elections related questions really pollutes this SE, since it's not what it was aimed for originally.

Comment: This is rather like complaining that there are too many questions about JavaScript on StackOverflow. The questions are there, because the people's interest is there. If we want more questions about other things, we need to cultivate more interest in other things.

Comment: I would note that this is also a trend in Global political science. American Politics makes up a very important part of Political Science globally, in part because there is a lot of interest even outside the U.S. and because if you define "opinion" and "answers" narrowly, then American Politics are frequently the only place where you can have questions and answers. If we want broader discussion, we have to accept broader definitions.

Comment: Well, my interest is not there. I would be interested about questions about American politics in general, but not those specifically about current elections and current candidates.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I the only one who think there is way too many questions about US elections

Perhaps not, but it's unclear that we should change anything.  First, this is an English language site (that is itself in the USA).  That strongly suggests that a lot of the questions are going to be about the USA, the UK, Australia, and Canada.  Of those four, the USA is by far the biggest (more people than the other three put together).  And the USA is in the middle of a political season, increasing current interest.  We may start getting more Australian questions for the same reason.

If you think that there are too many questions about USA-specific politics, the easiest thing to do is to block the [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag.  Then you won't have to see them.

You might consider if the real problem isn't that there are too few *other* questions on the site.  We still have questions whose last activity was five days ago on the front page.  Many sites refresh the front page daily.  Perhaps the problem is that there aren't enough questions about anything else, not too many USA questions.  The fix for that seems obvious:  ask more questions.

Comment: I'm actually surprised at the dearth of questions regarding Quebec issues. Perhaps it's timing.

Comment: Actually I already set my account to gray out the united-states tag, and sometimes almost the whole front page is grayed out so much there's only questions about this.

Comment: @user4012 I would love to see questions on Quebec issues if people wanted to ask them.